# Why does big-integer give me `0` when calculating the following expression?

Tags: javascript, math, biginteger

I'm using  [big-integer](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) module to deal with big numbers. When I'm trying to calculate the following expression I get `0`:

```
console.log(bigInt('13775000000000000000').divide('2500000000000000000000')); // 0
```

But when trying to calculate in pure JS numbers it gives me `0.00551`:

```
console.log(13775000000000000000 / 2500000000000000000000); // 0.00551
```

Why it so?

Comment: The closest integer to `0.00551` is `0`.

Comment: How can I retrieve same result when using `bigInt` library?

Comment: Use an arbitrary-precision library like [bignumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js). You can't do it with [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) since that is only for integers.

Comment: @Paulpro, thanks for the explanation. This library is that I need :)

Comment: @Paulpro That's not the reason. The fractional digits are discarded, no rounding involved.

Comment: @Erik: you do know that integers are so called "whole numbers", and that 0.00551 is not a whole number? In other words, BigIntegers are not a good way to calculate fractions.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js#dividenumber):

> divide(number)
>
> Performs integer division, disregarding the remainder.

So the result is zero.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

> ## divide(number)
>
> Performs integer division, disregarding the remainder.

Divide method performs integer divison.

---

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

```
1 / 2      // returns 0.5 in JavaScript
1 / 2      // returns 0 in Java 
// (neither number is explicitly a floating point number)
```

JS's `/` performs floating point number divison.